# Skip required custom option validation of simple product in magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9

I am trying to modify default magento functionality.
On product page i have two custom option of a simple product.

1. Color with option (Red, Blue, Black, Custom)
2. Size with option (S, L, XL)

I have added one extra filed in admin custom option area to add extra value for Custom color option.

Now i want to do following,

When i select Color = Custom, want to hide Size and user can add product without Size option. Both Option (Color and Size) are required.

I want to skip validation for only Custom color option. I am new to magento so dont know how to achieve this. Please suggest me something.

Thanks,

**UPDATE:**

I have added code to show/hide option base on selection. But when i click on add to cart button, i am getting error message **Please specify the product required option(s).**

Answer (score 2):

Please go to admin panel.

**Catalog -> Attributes -> Manage attributes**

Select your attribute, for example **color** and change **Values Required** to **No**

[image]

[image]

Comment: Vadym, i am not using attributes. I am using custom option of simple product. And i dont want to change Value Required to No. As it required for other options.

Comment: Color attribute uses custom options. Like red, white, etc. ... Please see second screen.

Comment: You are right, but this is Attribute. When i am using custom option of magento.